# SQL Vulnerability Assessment Error in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, powershell, vulnerability-assessment

I am running Vulnerability Assessments against my SQL Servers and databases using the PowerShell cmdlets `Invoke-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan` and `Export-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScan`, however, I am hitting an error on one database.

I receive the error

> Scan size: 50864310 is greater than 10485760 bytes.

The scan JSON file is nearly 50 MB in size, whereas the other scans for databases on this server are < 10 MB in size, which seems to be a limit for the PowerShell cmdlet to export.

SSMS is able to run the scan and export the file without any issues. Is there any way around this scan result size limitation using the PowerShell cmdlets?